# Converting between GPT and MBR hard drive without losing data

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, gpt

**NOTE:** I don't know a lot about hard drives so you're going to have to work with me here.

My question: Can I change my hard drive from GPT to MBR without losing data on it?

**NOTE:** there isn't an operating system on the laptop which I'm going to do this on. I'm going to boot from a USB and try to convert it.

Comment: You have to assume that data will be lost, so take a back-up first.

Comment: @AFH how can I make a back up if I can't boot the laptop ?

Comment: Converting is not possible. You have to remove the partition and create a new one. GPT is superior to MBR though, so I would keep GPT. One of the limits of MBR is the maximum size a partition can be. I believe 2 TB is its limit.

Comment: If you boot a diagnostic disc or a Linux Live system, then you can back up from there.

Comment: Yes that's possible. But you have to delete the OS partition to proceed. Use any bootable partition manager e.g. [link](http://getintopc.com/softwares/utilities/minitool-partition-wizard-technician-9-1-bootable-iso-download/).

Comment: It's true that GPT is superior to MBR, therefore many partition layouts cannot be converted to MBR; but some layouts can. Post the result of Linux command `gdisk -l /dev/sdX` (substitute `sdX` with your HDD) so we can tell more.

Comment: Also: are you going to boot OS from this HDD?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this conversion? It may not be necessary, and in fact may be quite inadvisable. OTOH, there *are* some legitimate reasons to want to do this (such as if you want to use the disk with a GPT-unaware OS).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/963178/how-do-i-convert-my-linux-disk-from-mbr-to-gpt-with-uefi

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can convert from GPT to MBR and MBR to GPT without data loss (I have tried that) with `gdisk` in Linux.

> Use at your own risk

Run command `gdisk /dev/sdx` with **sdx** as per your HDD partition

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
MBR: MBR only
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format.
THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q' if
you don't want to convert your MBR partitions to GPT format!
***************************************************************


Command (? for help):
```

### MBR to GPT

Enter **w** to write GPT partition on disk.

Press **y** to confirm your choice.

### GPT to MBR

Enter **r** to enter in *recovery and transformation options*.

Enter **g** to convert GPT to MBR partition.

### For Information

You can check table by command **p**.

> **Warning**: You will lose your boot loader (Ex. GRUB)

You can check if your partition is GPT or MBR now **`gdisk /dev/sdx`** with **sdx** as per your HDD partition in **Partition table scan(p)**

Comment: For more on this subject, see the [official GPT fdisk documentation on such conversions.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html)

Comment: Something's not right. In `gdisk` recovery and transformation options the **g** option will only recreate the protective MBR on top of the GPT but not actually convert the disk to GPT. The right way to convert a GPT disk to MBR is using `fdisk` **o** option but it _does_ destroy data on the disk.

Comment: I observed this behaviour with gdisk v1.0.3 and fdisk from util-linux 2.33.1 when I was trying to convert an empty GPT disk (no partitions) to MBR

Comment: "Converting" MBR to GPT this way (from a terminal in GParted or some other live distro) is good enough to get Windows 10 to install in UEFI mode, so even if it's not 100% right it's just what I need. (I care about keeping data because I dumped the disk structure from an old machine using Clonezilla and then am putting the new Win 10 in unallocated space.)

Comment: Should I use `gdisk` when it is saying `THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE!`?

Comment: It worked for me too without data loss. Although it warned me multiple times about probability of data loss. thanks

Comment: This successfully converted my disk back to MBR but did not mark the Windows partition as Active and the disk was not bootable. I ended up using DISM to clone the Windows partition after doing a fresh install to restore the structure of the disk while preserving data.

Comment: After this `r` -> `g` command, you still need to use `w` to write and quit. Until then, it seems nothing has happened yet (verify in another terminal with e.g. `fdisk -l /dev/sdx`).

Answer (score 11):

### Making your drive bootable

This is an enhancement to the information provided by Krunal and clarkttfu with more details on the steps to create a BIOS boot partition and install grub to it.

If you are changing the partition table on a a boot drive you will need to create a new "BIOS boot partition" for grub to store the bootloader in. These examples use the drive /dev/sda which will usually be the boot drive.

First, validate that there is space before the current first partition to support a boot partition, fisk -l should show that the first partition starts at sector 2048:

```
johnf@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[...]
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 125829119 125327362 59.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 125829119 125327360 59.8G 8e Linux LVM
```

If it does then you have the space required to create the partition. **If it doesn't you cannot follow these instructions and have a bootable system.**

Use gdisk to convert the partition to gpt, you can now create a new partition for your MBR, run sudo gdisk /dev/sd, enter `n` to create a new partition, accept the proposed partition number, you should be able to select a first sector of 34, set the partition type of ef02:

```
Command (? for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2):
First sector (34-4294967262, default = 4294922240) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 34
Last sector (34-2047, default = 2047) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): ef02
Changed type of partition to 'BIOS boot partition'
```

You can now write your partition table with `w`. Run partprobe again and then install grub:

```
johnf@ubuntu:~$ sudo partprobe
johnf@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

You should now be able to reboot your machine without issue.

Comment: It didn't work on ubuntu 20.04. When I use gdisk to write new boot partition, GPT is restored. Any way to create boot partition without losing MBR again?

Comment: works for me on 18.04

Answer (score 2):

As Krunal said, gdisk will ruin your grub, to avoid rescue mode:

If boot from BIOS, you'd better create a [BIOS boot partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#BIOS_systems) before you write and quit gdisk. (Otherwise a EFI partition is required if boot from UEFI).

And you `grub-install /dev/sda` to fix your bootloader then reboot and good luck.

i.e. I used the 2048 sectors between sda1 and sda5, exactly 1MB for BIOS boot partition:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          999423   487.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   5         1001472        41940991   19.5 GiB    8E00  Linux LVM
```