# Unbootable KVM guest

Tags: linux, grub, mbr, gpt

I've tried to shrink the root partition of a KVM guest. I managed to shrink it without data loss (as far as we consider only the data inside it, that is), but now the system does not boot anymore.
It's a Debian system, root partition is `/dev/mapper/vg0-root` (LVM). If I boot [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) I can mount it and I can access all the contents.

In order to shrink it, I did the following while booted in a live SystemRescueCD:

1. `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg0-root`
2. `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg0-root 25G`
3. `lvreduce -r --size 30G /dev/mapper/vg0-root`
4. `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 30G /dev/vda1`
5. `gdisk /dev/vda`

Please note I'm writing those steps by memory, maybe that is not the exact syntax I used, but it gives a clue of what I've done.

In `gdisk` I wanted to shrink the partition, and I did so by removing the existing partition and creating a new one with same starting sector (2048), same type (8E00 Linux LVM), but smaller size (30G instead of 200G). `gdisk` was suggesting as starting sector 34 instead of 2048, but I didn't want to move the partition, so I entered 2048 manually.

Then I rebooted the system, but grub hung. Back in SystemRescueCD, I mounted the LVM root partition under `/mnt/custom` and tried to reinstall GRUB:

1. `mount /dev/mapper/vg0-root /mnt/custom`
2. `cd /mnt/custom`
3. `mount -o bind /dev dev`
4. `mount -o bind /proc proc`
5. `mount -o bind /sys sys`
6. `chroot . /bin/bash`
7. `grub-install /dev/vda`

Here the result is:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform
 Warning: not using lvmetad with older version.
 Warning: not using lvmetad with older version.
 Warning: not using lvmetad with older version.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for RAID and LVM install.
```

Now I suspect that using `gdisk` instead of `fdisk` above, it implicitly  converted the partition table from MBR to GPT, I'm not sure but now I see a GPT partition table even with `fdisk`, so it's very likely IMHO.

Is there a way to make it MBR again? Or, is there tutorial to upgrade a Debian system from grub-pc to grub-efi manually, from a live CD system and a chroot?

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought, here is the solution to [convert GPT back to MBR](https://superuser.com/questions/1250895/converting-between-gpt-and-mbr-hard-drive-without-losing-data).

In short, run `gdisk /dev/vda`, use `r`, then `g`. It worked.

Comment: However I'm courious to know if there is a way to ugrade to GPT using a live CD and a chroot environment, so if anyone wants to chime in with that kind of solution, I could accept that answer instead of mine, thanks