# Windows 10 Home (1809 version) from EFI to BIOS or to QEMU (Virtual machine)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, bios, uefi, qemu

**Old (Downvoted) Post:**

I have installed Windows 10 in my SSD disk, and made the mistake to install in EFI mode ... (I don't want EFI in my new installation because it will be multi-boot system with some linux distributions some not available for EFI installations... I also don't see any reason to use EFI). Now I want to move this installation with the updates and my personal settings and files in another disk but not in EFI mode. The disk where I want to install windows 10 is the original disk which I purchased my Laptop and where the windows was installed. I already used the windows tool to backup the whole system but it gave just some folders and not an ISO file.

How (if possible) could I move this installation to the other disk but in BIOS and not EFI  mode?

Is it easier to just reinstall (and do all the updates) from scratch (not really many programs are installed but some of them takes time like TeXlive and Qtcreator)

Finally, could it be possible and legal to move it in a KVM QEMU virtual machine (no several installations but just the one I think I have the right to have) inside an external disk (I have a disk case external or even additional -instead of DVD drive-) or again a fresh install should be used and what is the way to make this installation because earlier I had used a fake way (answered that I changed my hardware to let windows allow me to install in virtual machine).

Virtual machine is not necessary for me but preferred if possible without losing the right to use it legally.

**New Post**

As far as I understood from the comments, I should install from scratch because the migration from UEFI to BIOS is not officially supported and this way would be easier than editing manually (or something) my boot options. (Sorry if still not clear but don't really know how Windows and UEFI boot works).

So, my request now is to move the installation even as an UEFI installation but inside a virtual machine (UEFI boot will be iconic -not real- there). This move should be legal (I read during installation that I have the right to use my purchased version of Windows in a virtual machine as far as I use only one such installation and as far as I use it for the PC (laptop) that the installation was legal for.). Ithought I could create an ISO file from my current installation that could include my settings and programs installed and I could use it to install in my virtual box ... But seems this is not possible .... So, I am looking for the way that this installation could move in a virtual box (QEMU in debian -but I don't think it matters-) or for a way to install legally in virtual box (The way I found was to download some version of windows for vitrual machine ... but in the agreement it forbids to use your key to turn the installation into normal installation ... It has to be used only for testing purposes as they making clear in this agreement.)

PS: Also answers to turn installation from UEFI to BIOS -like the first given below- (somehow easy way) are really appreciated and accepted for the bounty too.

Comment: Migrating from BIOS to UEFI is officially supported, but the other way is not. It's possible to do it manually, but it will be a PITA. It's probably a better idea to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks @gronostaj ... I will wait for virtual box solutions then if possible (in there the UEFI is virtual anyway and I don't care ... I will have the options of the other OSs before reach windows UEFI)

Comment: I suppose the -1 is from someone that loves UEFI so much ... Well ... I don't ... The bounty is for an answer about virtual machine (QEMU) legal installation (move the current installation if possible) or the reason that I should install from scratch in a virtual machine (If it is still legal as I read when first installed).

Comment: Your question is actually receiving downvotes due to it being unclear.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound ... I will try to improve it (my English are not really good enough neither my knowledge on UEFI/Windows... But you are possibly right because I remember that when wrote it I didn't knew what exactly could be done on this ...)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd

Comment: @ssnobody ... Really Really thanks ... I will try that tonight ... Seems this is what I wos looking for ... I will try to use the current answer from Daniel B first and then this... So, please make it an answer (with some comments if you wish) to accept it if this works .... [Once I will have more reputation and this work I will offer an additional bounty (So, both answers will take one)]. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I think a proper answer should have the actual steps to get your Win 10 system booting in QEMU, and although I used the tool I recommend to migrate my Windows 7 (MBR based) installation to VirtualBox, I wouldn't know how to be specific enough to target Windows 10 and QEMU. Still, once you have a vhd your life should be much easier. I encourage you to takes notes during your migration and write your own answer if it would be more complete than those given. Lastly, if you aren't particularly tied to QEMU and you have problems, I'd suggest you try to get it working on VirtualBox

Comment: An EFI install enables Secure Boot, which ensures the Windows bootloader is protected from malware modification _(installing Windows in CSM mode will also likely lock you to the MBR partition scheme with a max of 4 partitions in Windows)_.  It's also perfectly possible to install Windows in EFI mode and multi-boot non-EFI compatible OSes... simply switch to CSM mode, disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS _(many UEFI firmwares allow doing so via the Boot Options Menu)_, which will allow those non-EFI OSes to boot, hiding the boot option for any EFI enabled installs.

Comment: Thanks @JW0914. Using secure boot in many cases doesn't allow many linux installations... I want to have multiboot and thus always using a gpt partition scheme and bios installations... Currently I have this bad for me boot of EFI in windows (that for my laptop is the first boot if not press F9) and bios installations for my linux OSs... So, I want to avoid the need of this F9 and the usage of EFI in general

Comment: @koleygr Is it still possible to use a GPT partition table with Secure Boot disabled?  If not, that would be the major feature drawl, as 3 of the MBR partitions are used by Windows when the ideal configuration of WinRE, boot, and OS partitions is utilized, leaving only one extra primary partition available for usage to the user when compared to the limitless partitions GPT supports.

Comment: @JW0914 Of course you can use gpt partition table with secure boot disabled ... You have to create at the begining of your disk a small unformatted partition with bios-grub flag and this will be used for your boot... Of course you need at least one linux installations to install grub in the disk (not in the partition -but this partition will be used from grub-)... This is my settings always and I use many times even more than 10 linux plus my windows (from time to time). Some times Windows breaks your boot options (Windows doesn't like been one between others. Prefer to be by its own.Fixable!)

Answer (score 3):

I will not try to recall the UEFI--BIOS conversion procedures because there is already an answer about it and a few useful comments. From my point of view it seems a bit complicated a procedure, but it might still be worth the effort for the benefit of learning?

## Switching to a virtual environment

Converting the HDD to a virtual machine format is possibly the easiest part. Note that `disk2vhd` suggested in the comments converts to `vhd`. If you want to use the VM with `qemu`, it would possibly be beneficial to have an image in `.qcow2` format (conversion tools like `qemu-img` exist, but it's a thing to watch out for).

The interesting part is after the conversion: Depending on the "storage driver" selected in QEMU it is very well possible that Windows does not recognize its (newly virtual) hard drive and thus fails to boot.

Avoiding this problem can be as easy as "uninstalling" the HDD from the running Windows before making the virtual machine image but it can get arbitrarily more complicated if that does not work.

Additionally, consider the potential necessity for resizing the virtual HDD with respect to its original one.

There is actually an advanced and nifty trick to avoid all these issues: It is using the Windows installation disk as an "image restoring" program because that is what it is actually doing behind the scenes. The difficult part is to provide an image in a suitable format, i.e. in WIM.

German computer magazine c't has published a tool for automating the process: https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/c-t-WIMage-3863074.html
(I am not sure if any resource of that kind exists in English :( ).

From a legal point of view, I understand the license just like you: Moving Windows to a VM is OK in the scenario at hand.

## Dual Boot with UEFI is not as bad as it might sound

Initially, you wrote about dual-boot ideas. This is actually one of the "benefits" advertised for UEFI that you will no longer be in the situation of multiple OSes each trying to install their own boot loader in the MBR of the first disk -- with UEFI the firmware provides a dedicated menu to select the system to start from.

*OT?: As a Linux-Fan, I am of course also interested to know which distribution you want to install that does not support UEFI boot as of today :) I am still on "legacy BIOS" with all of my systems, but that is mainly beacuse of reduced experience with UEFI (and no such thing like dual boot here, one "mother" OS and the rest is VMs such that all can run in parallel as long as there is enough RAM for everything).*

Comment: Thanks @linux-fan ... I am using mostly devuan (that contains supports UEFI) but I am installing many times some i386 old distros on old notebooks that can't run a x64 version and just using these versions offline (to be safe but keep these notebooks alive)... Also I don't really like UEFI because in my mind is just a more complicated and resource hungry way (even if I have enough space on my disks) and mostly because I don't want a larger than my bios setup to "take care" of my settings and OSs (In short I don't really trust it :P ). Limiting Windows in a VM makes me feel safer... Thanks +1

Comment: Yes, the new UEFIs with Internet access can be a bit intimidating. Of course I am with you on running Windows in VMs (I do that all the time). Wrt. disk space I do not think there is a great difference between UEFI/BIOS. Their code resides in the motherboard's ROM. The UEFI boot partition does not contain much data beyond what's normally on a Linux `/boot` partition. I am keeping my old i386 systems alive as well :)

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that [QEMU does support booting a physical drive](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#host_005fdrives). I have successfully converted a Windows 10 EFI installation to boot in QEMU and retained the ability to boot the drive directly. However, satisfying Windows Activation is an entirely separate problem if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Offline conversion in either direction is very easy using a Windows Setup medium and `bcdboot`. You also need to change the partition table (GPT/MBR) appropriately or clone your Windows partition to a new disk with the correct partition table.

Changing the partition table is the hardest part, because Microsoft does not offer tools for this. I’d use `gdisk` for this, but it’s an expert tool. [See here](https://superuser.com/a/1252393/219095).

On GPT, a UEFI System Partition is also required, formatted using FAT32. On MBR, a boot partition is created by the Windows Setup but optional. I don’t recommend creating one unless required because you can only have 4 primary partitions.

On MBR, the Windows or boot partition needs to be “active”.

Once you have the Windows partition (and optionally the boot partition) ready, just use `bcdboot`:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows
```

You can learn [more about `bcdboot` here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di).

You can easily bring up a command prompt in Windows Setup using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB... I will look on this suggestions soon... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add here the option of
[Physical-to-Virtual (P2V)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual).

In the comments was already raised the option of using
[Disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd),
although its output format of
[VHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29)
is awkward to use in the context of this post.

You may want to check out the
[libguestfs project](http://libguestfs.org/).
Its 
[virt-v2v tool](http://libguestfs.org/virt-p2v.1.html)
might be what you're searching for:

> Virt-p2v converts a physical machine to run virtualized on KVM,
>   managed by libvirt, OpenStack, oVirt, Red Hat Virtualisation (RHV), or
>   one of the other targets supported by
>   [virt-v2v(1)](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v.1.html).
>
> Normally you don’t run the virt-p2v program directly. Instead you have
>   to boot the physical machine using the bootable CD-ROM, ISO or PXE
>   image. This bootable image contains the virt-p2v binary and runs it
>   automatically. Booting from a CD-ROM/etc is required because the disks
>   which are being converted must be quiescent. It is not safe to try to
>   convert a running physical machine where other programs may be
>   modifying the disk content at the same time.

Some random references which might be useful:

- [Red Hat manual Chapter 5. Converting physical machines to virtual machines](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/v2v_guide/chap-v2v_guide-p2v_migration_converting_physical_machines_to_virtual_machines)
- [Tutorial: Moving a Centos physical server with Soft RAID to be a KVM virtual machine guest using virt-p2v and virt-v2v](https://nevermind.dk/nevermind/blog.nsf/subject/tutorial-moving-a-centos-physical-server-with-soft-raid-to-be-a-kvm-virtual-machine-guest-using-virt-p2v-and-virt-v2v)

---

Another tool you may use is
[Clonezilla](https://www.clonezilla.org/).

See for example the article
[Migrate to a virtual Linux environment with Clonezilla](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-clonezilla/).

---

As regarding licensing issues, the usage you are contemplating is in a legally
gray area.

The
[MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm)
says this:

> d.      Multi use scenarios.
>
> (iv)    Use in a virtualized environment. This license allows you to
>   install only one instance of the software for use on **one device,
>   whether that device is physical or virtual**. If you want to use the
>   software on more than one virtual device, you must obtain a separate
>   license for each instance.

Strictly speaking, it may be argued that the QEMU virtual environment is
not the same as your physical computer.
But it may also be argued that you are only virtualizing a licensed
environment and renouncing the physical one, so you are not using the same
license in two environments.

As the argument may go both ways, I suggest not going too deeply into
the legal issues.
My experience with a previous Windows version was that after the P2V phase
Windows stayed activated (but never tried it with Windows 10).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc ... Tonight I will give a try to check all the answers and commands and see what is the best option for this ... I will try to keep some notes of what done and if I succeed (I will ask MS support too to confirm my way is legal) I will post it as an answer... Your answer seems for me really good and on the point.

Comment: If the Windows 10 license is retail and not OEM, it is within your rights to migrate it, without any negative legal issues.

Comment: Thanks ... I purchased my laptop with windows 10 pre-installed (a new licence not used) and thus I suppose it is an OEM... So, I will ask to be sure.... Thanks. My licence is digital activated on this pc and this makes me to understand it is an OEM.

Comment: You are very likely correct.

Comment: The most helpful in the post was about clonezilla and the link there ... thanks ... I am on the process and will come back to add a full answer and the results ... Also I will offer an additional bounty to other post that helped me... Thanks!