# Cannot boot Fedora on one PC

Tags: linux, boot, bios, fedora, uefi

I've problem with my Fedora 32 boot.

Firstly, sorry for my ignorance in this topic and sorry if I wrote something wrong.

---

#### What's going on?

I don't see it as bootable in my Asus UEFI BIOS UTILITY, but I still can boot it from another PC with older BIOS. Instead of this, I see my disk as "non uefi", I can set it as "boot drive", but after restart I see alone blinking cursor in top left corner of the black  screen.
My motherboard: ASUS PB875-V

---

#### What did I before?

Few months ago I had same problem and I solved it reinstalling my Fedora (and I don't want to do this now). And it works fine... until yesterday when I changed my primary disk to another Fedora drive. Of course, I can't boot from it, because it is Linux. Nextly I tried to switch back to my primary drive but for now it still doesn't work.

---

#### What did I try?

- disable Secure Booot mode,
- edit CSM options
- add fedora key (something like that I saw on yt on older BIOS systems) - always returns error.
  And it didn't change anything.

---

What should I do? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with your disk partition scheme.

Your disk being "not uefi" probably means that it uses the old MBR boot partition scheme - that's why it works on an older BIOS motherboard, but not on your newer UEFI motherboard. This implies that you should use GPT scheme for your new installation.

In windows, you can check the partition scheme with `diskpart`, on linux you can use tools like `parted`/`gparted`.

If there is an option in your UEFI to support BIOS/MBR, you should try that and see if it works. UEFI *can* support both GPT and MBR, but BIOS only supports MBR. If that's not possible, you'll have to reinstall your fedora in GPT mode - or try to convert your MBR boot partition into GPT boot partition. It can be done, but I wouldn't recommend it to an average user ...

Comment: 1. OP wants to avoid reinstalling _"I solved it reinstalling my Fedora (and I don't want to do this now)"_; 2. They've already played with CSM options; 3. BIOS can boot from properly created GPT disks thanks to protective MBR.

Comment: In other words, I'm not sure if your post actually answers anything. This installation allegedly worked and now it doesn't. CSM would be my first guess, but OP says they've tried playing with it and it didn't help.

Comment: I found this answer: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1252393/1195485)
After checking my disk I got response: 
- MBR: protective
- BSD: not present
- APM: not present
- GPT: present
"Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT."

Comment: About my CSM settings:
Boot Device Control: UEFI and Legacy 0pROM; 
Boot from Network Devices: Legacy 0pROM first; 
Boot from Storage Devices: Both, Legacy 0pROM first; 
Boot from PCIe/PCI Expansion Devices: Legacy 0pROM first;

Comment: I spoke too soon. How did you "change the primary disk" @SimonJan? Is it possible there were any changes in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @hextech I had plugged out it and in this place I plugged in another drive.
_Firstly I had tried to plug it in another place, but it didn't work._
And I can't answer to it _„Is it possible there were any changes in /etc/fstab”_