# Why does the OS boot from ext4 on a particular PC only?

Tags: boot, mbr, ext4

I've installed Manjaro on a USB stick to carry with me. However, I can boot from it only on the machine I used to install. On other PCs, the BIOS or UEFI does not recognize the drive as bootable.

The device `/dev/sda` has a single partition `/dev/sda1` formatted as `ext4`. There is a `/boot/` directory there, with `/boot/initramfs-6.5-x86_64.img` and other files there. The partition has the `boot` flag.

---

`$ mount` displays the following:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8158880k,nr_inodes=2039720,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=36,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=14490)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=8175772k,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1635152k,nr_inodes=408788,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1001,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001)
```

---

`$ df -Th` shows

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev            devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
run            tmpfs     7.8G  1.5M  7.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4      458G  103G  332G  24% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G   96K  7.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  132K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

`# blkid` (with elevated privileges) returns

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="419d4f22-7fd6-42ea-a273-4e54028197ce" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b1e4001d-01"
```

---

`# fdisk -l /dev/sda` reports

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: SSD 870 EVO 500G
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb1e4001d

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G 83 Linux
```

---

Finally, if it's even relevant, `# gdisk -l /dev/sda` writes

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model: SSD 870 EVO 500G
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DC55B4BD-D878-4752-9414-E4CE82C33258
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2029 sectors (1014.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       976773119   465.8 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
```

---

Now, how do I make the USB stick more portable? Does it worth converting MBR to GPT, as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1252393/969363)? I'd prefer not to re-install the OS.

---

*Edit:*  As I'm using the USB stick right now, I can't test any propositions right away. I'll do my best to try them within 24 hours.

Comment: Do the other PCs have "BIOS compatibility" / "CSM" mode enabled or not? There could be several whys but that's the major one.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, thanks, I'll take a look. I haven't noticed such a line in the interface. As a side note, as I'm using the USB stick right now, I can't test the propositions right away. I'll mark that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your other PCs have UEFI *without the BIOS-compatibility feature* (either because it was disabled out-of-the-box, or because it's outright no longer supported with certain modern systems).

The "working" PC was booting the USB stick in BIOS mode (UEFI-style firmwares call it "legacy mode" or "CSM mode") because that's the only mode that your drive currently contains boot code for. That works because BIOS boot never looks into *any* filesystems at all; it loads the bootloader from specific sectors directly.

UEFI will never recognize that drive as natively bootable, because the drive does not have any partitions with a compatible filesystem that could stand in for the EFI System Partition.

For native UEFI boot, the drive *doesn't* necessarily need to be GPT-partitioned, but it *does* need to have a FAT32 partition from which the firmware could load a `BootX64.efi` file which is your bootloader. (Some PCs can also read NTFS or exFAT, but the standard UEFI filesystem – and the only *guaranteed to work* filesystem – is FAT32.)

This serves a roughly similar purpose to having a separate `/boot` partition (when the real root filesystem is too complex for the bootloader); indeed it often *is* mounted at /boot, or sometimes at /efi.

So your steps would be:

1. Repartition it to have a small FAT32 partition (at least 2x the current total size of your /boot files) alongside the existing one. During a fresh install it traditionally goes at the beginning, but it can as well be placed at the end.

   - If you keep MBR partitioning, the partition's type in fdisk should be set to `EF`.
   - If you decide to use `gdisk` to convert to GPT partitioning, the type in gdisk should be `EF00` (gdisk's abbreviation for the actual EFI GUID).
2. Move all files from your current /boot to the new partition, and configure it to be mounted at /boot via /etc/fstab.
3. Install an UEFI-compatible bootloader at `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` in the new partition (that is, /boot/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi from Linux point of view).

   For example, with GRUB, specify `--target=x86_64-efi` as well as `--removable` to place the .efi file where UEFI will expect it. With systemd-boot, both are already the default.

Answer (score 2):

UEFI cannot boot from an `ext4` filesystem.

Your USB stick needs to have an [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) formatted with a FAT filesystem.

The systems that boot `ext4` successfully are either Legacy BIOS-based or have CSM enabled.